# Trying to timeit my sqrt function in Python

Tags: python, sqrt, timeit

So I've tried to code a simple square root function. I did, and I wanted to compare it with Python's original one. Here's my code:

```
from math import sqrt
import timeit

def sqrt2(number):
    i=1
    while i**2<number:
        i+=1
    left=float(i-1)
    right=float(i)
    temp = left+(right-left)/2
    while str(temp**2)!=str(number):
        if temp**2>number:
            right=temp
            temp = left+(right-left)/2
        elif temp**2<number:
            left=temp
            temp = left+(right-left)/2
        else:
            return temp
    return temp

print timeit.timeit("sqrt2(12)", number=10000, setup='from __main__ import sqrt2')
print timeit.timeit("sqrt(12)", number=10000, setup='from math import sqrt')
```

It simply takes the number and notices when and integer^2 is lower and when (integer+1)^2 is higher than our number, then divides the gap between those 2 by 2, and tries the middle number, etc. It's ok for me, but when I try to timeit.timeit it just stops, cursor in console shows, that it's still working, but nothing happens

Comment: `while str(temp**2)!=str(number)` - why is *that* your check?

Comment: cuz checkin' it without str() never really lets loop end, and this gets really nice ~ to our square root (6-7 numbers after ".")

Comment: it is better to check this condition with `math.abs(temp**2 - number) >= 1e-7`

Comment: but why make it a str?? that make no sense, that make you to fall in a infinite loop, because you do `str(number)`  that give "12" because number is a int, and because temp is a float, it always going to have a decimal point in its string form, so they always are going to be different...

Comment: @user502144: `abs` is in the built-in namespace, not the `math` module. Either don't qualify the name `abs` to use the built-in, or use `math.fabs` for explicitly floating point absolute value (that said, both of them do the same thing when the input is a `float`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the issue is that you get in an infinite loop here: `while str(temp**2)!=str(number):`

Your problem is that `temp**2` in a `float`, while `number` is an `int`. Since you compare their string representation, the first one will be, for example, `12.0`, and the second one, `12`.

You can either fix the condition in your `while` loop (using `str()` seems very odd indeed), or pass a `float` to your function.

And by the way, your implementation is very slow. A quick run with a float returns:

Yours: `0.461127996445`

python's: `0.000571012496948`

Comment: Correct, I mixed them up.